# How to disable the swipe feature to back view controller?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swipe, ios8.3

I want to disable swipe to back viewcontroller feature in `UIViewcontroller`. I put this line in `ViewDidLoad`but its not working.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

How can I disable that feature. Because I have a side menue (`SWRevealViewcontroller`). when I swipe the frontviewcontroller it goes back to my loging screen. How can I avoide this? Above line is not working for me.

Please help me.
Thanks